# Angular Video Dimension

Tags: angular, typescript, video

I wanted to know how can you display a video source's dimension i.e. the resolution(eg. 1200 x 720) in typescript ? 
I have an HTML Script such as

```
<video id="videoPlayer" src="some_video.mp4">
<source type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and I want to get some_video.mp4's resolution. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: you could create a DOM element, load the video into it and trapping the metadataloaded event retrieve the .width and .height properties...

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<video id="videoPlayer" src="some_video.mp4">
<source type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Script

```
<Script>
var vid = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
var videoHeight = vid.videoHeight; 
var videoWidth  =  vid.videoWidth; 
</Script>
```